# how to blink the drawn image on a video in c#?

Tags: c#, image-manipulation

I have a form,contains the video control.I am drawing one image on that video.but,I want to blink that image.
     Any ideas,please help me.

Answer (score 1):

set a timer and reload?

Answer (score 0):

Its a video control, so why don't run a video of blinking.